# How to set everything to silent except the alarm clock [7.1.1 Nougat]

Tags: calendar, automation, alarm, silent-mode, 7.1-nougat

Does anybody  know how to set everything to silent except the alarm clock? In priority only, and alarms only mode, both calendar reminders and alarm clock notifications make the phone vibrate. If I set it to full silent both are silenced.

Currently I'm using the business calendar app

I'd like to configure the calendar to only notificate in priority mode and not in alarms only mode.

(The problem I'm having is full day calendar appointments make my phone vibrate at midnight.)

Answer (score 3):

You can try to achieve this by automation. I prefer [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) being easy to learn and free

I don't have Nougat , so can't test it. I also recall  reading that *dnd* mode is behaviour is different compared to Marshmallow ( and don't remember how), so this may need further tweaking based on your revert

[image]

The way I understood your need and accordingly configured macro is

1. You are in Priority mode ( not alarm only )
2. Your calendar app sends a notification which needs to be seen by not heard ( select your  calendar app in Trigger, in the macro I chose default calendar app)

Comment: Please let me know if it worked or it needs to be improved. Thanks

Comment: Thanks!! I ended up using an action to delete a calendar notification on trigger of a calendar app notification while in constraint  priority mode.

Comment: Welcome :  ) all the best with automation

Comment: Unfortunately the phone sometimes still shortly vibrates when the calendar item triggers. I think the macrodroid script is top late to respond. (The notification does get cleared from lockscreen but only after it vibraties shortly)

Comment: That's strange . Will revert if I can find a reason

Comment: Can you try with a *wait 5 seconds* as first action (before any other action) and also in between actions of silence vibration and delete notification. This is to contrary to what you suspect but I am thinking that Macro needs more time. This can be reduced to 3 second later

Answer (score 0):

I eventually worked around the problem with the automate flow as pasted below. The flow however removes the ability for my calendar app to post notifications in a given time interval. Might a notification get through anyway the notification will get cancelled if the phone is in silent mode.

Just only cancelling the notification, and not removing the app ability to notificate, turned out to be too slow to prevent the phone from buzzing as was also the case with the solution with MacroDroid

[image: Automate flow]

Answer (score 0):

I found that volume down until vibrate, then more options from there. One of mine I tap 'None' then either for how long or indefinitely, and my other phone has a slider icon which lets you select which to silence.